# Integer solutions for an equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking for an expression yielding all the integers $a\geq 0$ such that

$$
\frac{ab}{c}-\frac{cd}{2}
$$

is integer, given $b$ and $c$ are integers, $d$ is rational, $b\geq 1$, $c\geq 1$ and $d\geq 0$.

It seems this equation is integer if and only if the floating part of $\frac{ab}{c}$ equals the floating part of $\frac{cd}{2}$. Am I right here ?

If so, I am looking for $a\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$
\frac{ab}{c}-\left\lfloor \frac{ab}{c}\right\rfloor\ = \frac{cd}{2}-\left\lfloor \frac{cd}{2}\right\rfloor\
$$

However, I cannot go further.

Any idea ?

Comment: First of all, the question is unclear, to me at least. Second, if it is clear to *you*, you should write down your thoughts and what you have tried. If it does not make sense to you, you should first try to interpret the problem and understand it before posting here. Good luck! :)

Comment: $d$ - you know?

Comment: I have updated my post with what I have been trying so far, but I think I lack some knowledge about number theory to go ahead...

Comment: Put $c=2t$ : $b=tk$  factors to select the appropriate parity.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but it is still not clear to me, can you give me more details please ?

Comment: Since a, b and c are integers, this result cannot possibly be an integer (or even rational) if d is not rational.

Comment: True, I have added this in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually don't think you need much knowledge of number theory to solve this problem. We need to find solutions to a such that $\frac{ab}{c} - \frac{cd}{2}$ is an integer. So, let us write $d$ as $\frac{e}{f}$. We then have that $\frac{ab}{c} - \frac{ce}{2f}$ is an integer - let us call this $k$.

This means that $\frac{2abf - c^2e}{2cf} = k$ and thus $2abf - c^2 e = 2cfk$, so $a = \frac{ck}{b} + \frac{c^2e}{2f}$, so $a = \frac{ck}{b} + \frac{c^2d}{2b}$ or $a = \frac{2ck+c^2d}{2b}$for any integer $k$. You can plug it in and see that it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think there is a little mistake in your last expression, since a=ck/b + c^2d/2b or a=(2ck+c^2d)/2b - I've just updated your answer accordingly.